# CVXPY - conic solver does not support the cones output by the problem

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization, cvxpy

I'm using cvxpy to sole a portfolio optimization problem with constraints on the maximum number of assets to consider.
In order to do that I want to introduce new variables 'yi' that are boolean so that they are equal to 1 if the asset `i` is included in the portfolio and 0 otherwise.
The sum of the 'yi' variables will be equal to 'k' which is the number of assets I want to consider.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from cvxpy import *

# assets names
tickers = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF"]

# return matrix
ret = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1,6), columns = tickers)

# Variance_Coviariance matrix
covm = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6,6), columns = tickers, index = tickers)

# problem setting
x = Variable(len(tickers))                   # xi variables
y = Variable(len(tickers), boolean = True)   # yi variables
er = np.asarray(ret.T) * x                   # expected return
min_ret = 0.2                                # minimum return
risk = quad_form(x, np.asmatrix(covm))       # risk
k = 3                                        #maximum number of assets to include
constraints = [sum(x) == 1, er >= min_ret, x >= 0, sum(y) == k]  #constraints array
for i in range(len(tickers):
    constraints.append(x[i] <= y[i])         # additional constraint for which each xi must be less or equal to each yi
objective = Minimize(risk)                   # set the objective function
prob = Problem(objective, constraints)       # set problem
prob.solve()                                 # solve problem
```

I get the following error:

```
 Either candidate conic solvers (['GLPK_MI']) do not support the cones output by the problem (SOC, NonNeg, Zero), or there are not enough constraints in the problem.
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: What is `n`? Your code - as given -  does not run. In addition, your example with random data does not guarantee the covariance matrix is always PSD, which rightly gives me an error. Can you provide a program such that the problem is reproducible?

Comment: You need a solver that can handle MIQP (mixed integer quadratic programming) problems. Typically these are commercial solvers.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to switch n with len(tickers)

Comment: I am using real data that I am not able to provide. The random matrices are created just to give an idea of what I am doing.

Comment: Would I still need a quadratic solver even if I try to maximize return and fix risk instead?

Comment: Risk as a constraint makes it a MIQCP (mixed-integer quadratically-constrained program). Typically supported by commercial solvers.

Comment: I followed the steps at this link https://tirthajyoti.github.io/Notebooks/Portfolio_optimization.html
Are they not correct?

Comment: @GiovanniIsgreeen you have binaries `y`. That makes your model a mixed-integer program with a quadratic objective. The model you link to has no binaries, and is a regular quadratic program.

Comment: Mosek.com should be able to solve it. Not open source though.